# What is wrong with this code that it is not able to increment the stock by one in my Database

Tags: python, sqlite

I have written this code in python and using SQLite to interact with my database. I want the user to be able to return an item which is purchased, which works functionally, but now I need to actually increment the stock by 1 when an item is returned.

The code so far is like this:

```
                           itemToReturn = input("Enter the OrderItemsID of the item you want to return: ")
                            # sql statement to locate record based on input
                            itemToReturnSQL = '''UPDATE OrderItems
                                                SET OrderItemStatus = 'Returned'
                                                WHERE OrderItemsID = ? 
                                                '''
                            locateItemSQL = c.execute("SELECT ProductID FROM OrderItems WHERE OrderItemsID= ?", (
                                itemToReturn,))

                            locateItem = c.fetchall()

                            returnStockSQL = '''UPDATE Products
                                                SET ProductStock = ProductStock + 1
                                                WHERE ProductID = ?'''

                            # executes the sql
                            conn.execute(itemToReturnSQL, (itemToReturn,))
                            conn.execute(returnStockSQL, (locateItem[0][0],))
                            # saves
                            conn.commit()
```

Orders are divided into 2 tables:

```
Order: OrderID (Auto increment) UserID (foreign key) Order Date
OrderItems: OrderItemsID (Auto) OrderID (foreign key) ProductID(Foreign Key)
```

No errors are given now, but the stock still does not increment.

Comment: See what the value of `locateItem` is. You are passing it as the value of `ProductID`, but it is not a number.

Comment: `locateItem = c.fetchall()` makes `locateItem`  a list. You need to extract the integer value from it before attempting to insert it. If you **know** you will get one row back, consider using `fetchone` (but you would still need to extract the value)

Comment: ok, thanks for the advice on that, i am now using locateItem[0][0] as my paramter for returnStockSQL, however it is still not incrementing the stock, I'll edit the post

Comment: Nevermind, everythings good to go, just me being dumb testing. Thank you fort help